# How do you pass parameters to the controller using Backbone.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

In one of my backbone.js views I have the following code:

```
  events:
    'click .filter_classroom_size': 'filterClassroom'

  filterClassroom: (event)->
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.preventDefault()
    Backbone.history.navigate("classrooms?nationality", true)
```

My router has the following code:

```
  routes:
    'classrooms?:filter': 'classrooms'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Classrooms.Collections.Entries()
    @collection.fetch()

  classrooms: (filter) ->
    classroomView = new Seats.Views.ClassroomIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#output_container').html(classroomView.render().el)
    alert("#{filter}") # this prints out the filter parameter
```

classrooms_controller.rb:

```
class ClassroomsController < ApiController
  def show
    # How do I send a parameter here so I can filter on it?
    respond_with Classroom.all
  end
end
```

I want to be able to pass parameters into the controller so I can filter database results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Backbone uses [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) under the hood, so you can simply pass jQuery.ajax options inside methods such as `save`, `fetch` and `destroy`.

```
initialize: ->
  @collection = new Classrooms.Collections.Entries()
  @collection.fetch
    data:
      your_key: your_value
```

Comment: How do I send parameters from the view to the router to put in that `initialize` section? Also, I just put your example in the initialize section and outputted the params via `Rails.logger.info` in the controller and the key/value didn't show.

Comment: you could call the @collection.fetch({data:{filter:filter}}) when classrooms function is invoked, since you have the filter variable. About the logger, check out if your code is ident correctly, it should work.